# catkin_make error when using mavros

Tags: catkin-make, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Excuse me, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo.
I downloaded the mavros package  from https://github.com/mavlink/mavros.git, to the folder catkin_ws.
But when I run catkin_make, it came errors:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "control_toolbox"
  with any of the following names:

    control_toolboxConfig.cmake
    control_toolbox-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "control_toolbox" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "control_toolbox_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "control_toolbox" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  mavros/test_mavros/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sen/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/sen/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

why this happened? How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot if you could help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227296/catkin_make-error-when-using-mavros./) by [Shusen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26018/shusen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-02-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

There are two different possibilities than can cause this error.

1. You have not installed the control_toolbox package. To do this the following command should be enough.

   `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-control-toolbox`
2. If this is not the case and you already have installed it. Then there is a problem with the sourcing of that package. You have to make sure that the route where that package is installed is in the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Just do a `echo  $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`  to see the paths in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shusen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26018/shusen/) on 2016-02-22**:
Thaks a lot! The first command solved my problem.